# How to print barcode generated inside a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, thymeleaf

This is my html code alongside thymeleaf. Here, in the `div` barcode is properly generated as I need it. But while printing it with my barcode printer I'm unable to print it properly. Is there any way to print barcode properly using css or  media query or media print?

```
<div th:id="'barcode'+${status.index}" style="margin-left:105px; width:100px;"> 
</div>
<a class="btn btn-info"  th:id="'print'+${status.index}" href="#" 
   th:onclick="'printValue('+${status.index}+');'" >Generate Barcode
</a>
```

This is my JavaScript function to generate the barcode and print it:

```
function printValue(x){
    $("#barcode"+x).barcode($("#txtbarcode"+x).val(),"code128");
    $("#barcode"+x).rotate(90);
    $.print("#barcode"+x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the **barWidth** and **barHeight** parameters like:

```
$("#barcode"+x).barcode(
  $("#txtbarcode"+x).val(),
  "code128",
  { barWidth: 1, barHeight: 50 }
);
```